# Use another machine as a proxy server for my computer

Tags: proxy, windows-server-2008

I'm not able to connect to most of the websites from my machine (Win XP) due to the blocking done by administrators. But the same websites are allowed in one of our servers (Windows Server 2008). Can I, by any means, use the server machine as a proxy server for my machine and browse the blocked websites from my machine? Is there any way for this?

Comment: If the server is set up as a proxy then yes, otherwise no. The server has to be set up to pass connections through.

Comment: @Mokubai: I'm not sure if the server is setup as a proxy. How do I verify that? If not, then how do I setup it as a proxy?